# How to sort a cell array in Octave by a column of floats?

Tags: sorting, octave

I created a cell array in Octave.  Some columns contain floats, and some columns contain strings.  I am able to sort the cell array by a column of *strings* (say col #4), using this command:

```
sortrows (mycellarray, 4);
```

But if the column I want to sort by is a column of *floats*, then I get this error message:

```
error: sort: only cell arrays of character strings may be sorted
```

Does anyone know how to sort a cell array, by a column of floats?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert the column with float values to a vector, sort it and get the sorting index. Then you can apply this index to your cell array.

```
mycellarray = {'a',1,0.5; 'b',2,0.1; 'c',3,4.5; 'd',4,-3.2};
vector2sort=cell2mat(mycellarray(:,3));
[~,idx] = sort(vector2sort)
mycellarraysorted = mycellarray(idx,:);
```

In some versions of Octave, however, the tilde `~` operator is not defined. In that case:

```
vector2sort = mycellarray(:,3); 
[dummy,idx] = sort(vector2sort); 
mycellarraysorted = mycellarray(idx,:);
```